# Interval of memory allocation

Tags: c, struct, malloc

```
struct Thing
{
    int member1;
    int member2;
};

struct Thing* heap()
{
    struct Thing* heap_thing = (struct Thing*)malloc(sizeof(struct Thing));

    heap_thing->member1 = 1;
    heap_thing->member2 = 2;

    printf("%p, %p, %p\n", heap_thing, &(heap_thing->member1), &(heap_thing->member2));

    return heap_thing;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct Thing* ptr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
       ptr = heap();
       free(ptr);
    }        
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the printed memory addresses would be something like:
(because `struct Thing` is 8 bytes)

```
0x000008, 0x000008, 0x00000c

0x000010, 0x000010, 0x000014

0x000018, 0x000018, 0x00001c ......
```

But what show on my screen are:

```
0x000008, 0x000008, 0x00000c

0x000018, 0x000018, 0x00001c

0x000028, 0x000028, 0x00002c ......
```

Why the memory address of the `struct Thing` members are not allocated to what I expected? The memory address between `ptr` has 16 bytes interval but not 8 bytes?

Comment: Don't do this `(struct Thing*)malloc(sizeof(struct Thing));` it's UNECESSARILY ugly. Just `malloc(sizeof(struct Thing));` is fine.

Comment: It's just a quick and dirty test, who cares if it has a memory leak lol

Comment: I care, memory leaks can be very mean. I prefer to always do everything right to avoid tragedies.

Comment: @iharob what you mean is, the pointer in the function takes up 8 bytes 0x00000c - 0x000018?

Comment: What does `sizeof(struct Thing)` give? Can you post the exact definition please?

Comment: But `sizeof(heap_thing)` gives me 4 bytes.

Comment: `sizeof(struct Thing)` gives me 8 bytes

Comment: Because on your system a pointer is 4 bytes. Which is weird because almost every system is 64 bits now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most memory allocators are not overhead-free -- there is some amount of extra memory used internally by the allocator preceding and/or following each allocated block.

In your system's memory allocator, this overhead appears to come out to eight bytes per allocated block. This is pretty typical for a 32-bit system; it's probably storing the size of the allocated block (4 bytes) and a pointer to the previous block (4 bytes), or something similar.

Another factor to keep in mind is that many allocators have a minimum allocation quantum -- that is, the "real" size of every allocated block is rounded up to the nearest multiple of a standard size. This is because certain CPU features (particularly vector operations) often require that memory be aligned to a certain boundary, and because very small blocks are awkward to keep track of. On your system, the quantum is probably eight bytes, though, so this isn't coming into play in your example. (You can probably demonstrate this effect by changing one of the members in your structure from an `int` to a `char`.)

Comment: I guess it's something like structure padding?